# Using a class in java

Tags: java, class, object

Suppose I want to use a class that someone else wrote in java, do I need to get access to the source code itself or is there another way?

Comment: As other said, no you do not need the source. Have you actually tried it and are having problems? Just wondering if there is another reason for your question.

Answer (score 3):

No, its not necessary to have the source code unless you need to understand the methods of the class. You can use the compiled java class that will (*usually*) be available as a jar distribution.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need the source code, just the compiled class, which is typically distributed in jar files.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them to compile it into a.jar

Answer (score 1):

you'd typically have a jar file published by the author of the class you're going to use

Answer (score 0):

You can get the compiled java class file and included that in your classpath. Normally it is good to have the source code with you because you can always reference if you are in doubt what actually the class methods do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use that class file in your programm, you don't need the source code. Yo can straight away call that class methods. In IDS like eclipse when you type dot after object name of that class , even yo can see all the methods available for outside work. But yes if you want to understand the code of that class you need source code  which you can get after decompilation of class too(if source code is not available)